# With one village on two devices, can I start over with one device?

Tags: ios, game-center, clash-of-clans

I connected my clash of clans village on both my iPod and iPhone.

Is there anyway I can unlink my iPod and start from the beginning there?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't Cash of Clans use Game Center for its integration?

So if you sign in on one device with a new Game Center ID, it should start with a new village.